# Repeated incomplete Steiner Triplets

Tags: combinatorics

I'm not a mathematician, so I hope this question makes sense. As a hobby, I organize leagues for amateur volleyball teams. To minimize travelling costs the matches are played as small tournaments with 3 teams, where everyone plays each other (2+1=3 matches). At the end of the season, all teams should have played each other the same amount of times. For the past seasons, the number of teams has been either 7 or 9, so it all worked out fine. This year there are 10 teams, so I discovered that some games have to be played as single games.

I then discovered that this has a name:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerTripleSystem.html

and that it is only possible to do if the number of teams mod 6 equals 1 or 3.

Is there an algorithm that for a given number v will minimize the number of "remaining" 2-tuples? Furthermore, under what circumstances is it possible to combine 2 or more such sets, so that the remaining 2-tuples can be combined into triplets?

As an example of when we can combine incomplete triplets is for 5 elements

```
S = {A, B, C, D, E}
```

If we repeat this process 3 times, it is possible to end up with:

```
A   B   C
E   B   D
D   C   E
C   A   D
B   A   E
A   D   E
C   B   E
D   A   B
E   A   C
B   C   D
```

I.e., everyone plays each other 3 times, with a total of 3*(4+3+2+1)=30 games.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Fascinating to see someone grappling with this in real life.  Remember doing some similar but contrived problems with these steiner triples in my combinatorics class.  Alas, I've likely forgotten more than I even learned :P

Comment: In the case of $10$ teams, you want each tea to play in $4$ triples and $1$ single match, giving $5$ single matches.  In order to reduce the number of single matches, you'd have to increase the number of triples, which is plainly impossible.  Or is your question how to set up such a schedule?

Comment: No, I dont really mind if some teams play all there games as triplets, and other teams play some games as single matches. My method now is to create an array of all games, then remove and merge them into triplets. I guess Im asking if it matters in what order I merge them, will there be a different number of unmatched games left in the array? Second question is whether I do this twice (or more), can the leftovers from array1 and array2 be used to create new triplets. The immediate problem concerns 10 teams but Im also curious about the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent a good deal of time this morning Googling this, and I have some information for you.

What you describe is called a "partial Steiner triple system" (PSTS).  That is, no pair can belong to more than one triple.  A PSTS is said to be *maximal* if no further triple can be added without violating the condition.  The order of a PSTS is the number of points (teams, in your application).  The spectrum of maximal PSTS's of order $v$ is the set of possible values of the number of triples in such a system.

The problem of determining the spectrum of a maximal Steiner triple system of order $v$ has been solved.  The results are summarized in Section 9 of [this paper](http://actamath.savbb.sk/pdf/acta2302.pdf).

Let's look at the case for $v=10.$  In the notation on page $16$ the spectrum is $S^{(3)}(10)$ and the largest element of the spectrum is $M^{(3)}(10)$.  Since $10\equiv4\pmod{6},$ we use the formula 
$$M^{(3)}(10)={v(v-2)-2\over6} = {10\cdot8-2\over6}=13$$

The smallest value in the spectrum is denoted $m^{(3)}(10)$.  To compute this we must first compute the number $\delta_v$.  Since $10\equiv10\pmod{12},$ we use the formula $$\delta_v=-2v+16=-2\cdot10+16=-4$$.

Now we use the formula $$
m^{(3)}(v)={v^2+\delta_v\over12}={10^2-4\over12}=8$$

This goes a long way to answering your question I think.  There are maximal PSTS's of order $10$ with as few as $8$ triples, so it seems highly unlikely that a naive greedy algorithm will produce a maximal PSTS with $13$ triples.

For completeness, let's finish computing the spectrum.  We know that $R(10)$ = $\{8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ contains all possible values, and we have to determine which values, if any, are omitted from the spectrum.

We first have to compute $Y(10)$.  We use the last formula, with $k=0,$ to find $Y(10)=11.$  There are some typos in the form for the set of omitted values, $Q(10)$, so it doesn't make any sense, but by using "Search Inside" on amazon.com, I was able to look at page $164$ of ["Triple Systems" by Coburn and Rosa](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198535767), to find that the correct formula is $$
Q(v)=\left\{s:m^{(3)}(v)<s<Y(v) \text{ and }\left\lfloor{v-1\over2}\right\rfloor\equiv1\pmod{2}\right\}$$  Since $9$ is the only integer between $8$ and $10$ and $\left\lfloor{9-1\over2}\right\rfloor\equiv0\pmod{2},$ we see that $Q(10)=\emptyset,$ so that the spectrum is exactly $R(10).$

I couldn't find any deterministic algorithms for generating maximal PSTS's on the Web.  For such small numbers as you are dealing with, I think the right approach is to write a script that computes $M^{(3)}(v)$ and then finds a maximal PSTS of this order by backtracking.

On page $174$ of "Triple Systems" a randomized algorithm called Rödl's "nibble method" is described. Start with an empty set choose a triple uniformly at random. If none of the pairs in the triple have already occurred, add it to the set.  Otherwise, discard it.  Continue until there are no candidate triples.  This is supposed to cover almost all the pairs, so if you know what the maximum is, you can just try a few times until you hit the jackpot.  This would be very easy to implement, of course.

**EDIT**

I wrote a python script implementing the "nibble method" as described above.  It works well so long as the number of teams doesn't get too big.  I've set the maximum number of random trials at $500$ and so far that's always bee enough, though with $12$ teams, it's come awfully close a number of times.

```
#mpsts.py
'''
Given n, construct a partial Steiner triple system on 
n points, containing as many triples as possible.
'''
from itertools import combinations 
from random import choice 
import sys

def M(n):
    m = n%6
    if m in (1,3):
        return n*(n-1)//6
    if m in (0,2):
        return n*(n-2)//6
    if m== 4:
        return (n*(n-2)-2)//6
    if m== 5:
        return (n*(n-1)-8)//6

def report():
    assert audit()
    print("%d points, %d triples, %d pairs, %d trials" %(n, len(triples), len(pairs)-len(usedPairs), trials))
    for t in triples:
        print(tuple(sorted(t)))
    for p in pairs:
        if p not in usedPairs:
            print(p)

def audit():
    if len(triples) != max3:
        return False
    if 3*max3 != len(usedPairs):
        return False
    return True

n = int(sys.argv[1])
max3 = M(n)  
pairs = set(combinations(range(1,n+1), 2))

trials = 1
maxTrials = 500
while trials <= maxTrials:
    candidates = list(combinations(range(1,n+1), 3))
    usedPairs = set()
    triples = set()
    while candidates:
        t = choice(candidates)
        p = set(combinations(t, 2))
        candidates.remove(t)
        if not (p & usedPairs):
            triples.add(t)
            usedPairs |= p
    if len(triples) ==max3:
        report()
        break
    trials += 1
else:
    print("no successes in %d trials"%maxTrials)
```

Here's sample output for $10$ teams:

```
10 points, 13 triples, 6 pairs, 3 trials
(1, 4, 7)
(2, 6, 7)
(3, 7, 9)
(4, 6, 9)
(1, 9, 10)
(1, 2, 3)
(7, 8, 10)
(3, 4, 10)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 8, 9)
(5, 6, 10)
(1, 6, 8)
(3, 5, 8)
(5, 9)
(4, 8)
(1, 5)
(3, 6)
(2, 10)
(5, 7)
```

Notice that $5$ occurs $3$ times in the $6$ leftover pairs at the end.  You might have a tournament with say, $1,5,\text{ and }9$ where $5$ played the other two teams, but $1$ and $9$ didn't meet again, or just had a "friendly."  I don't know if that would be considered fair.  It seems unfair to me if $5$ had to play all $3$ teams, but then, I don't know anything about volleyball.

Comment: Wow, amazing. I will look into the references you provided, thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks for the implementation, super-cool. This also helps with my followup-question. Assuming everyone should play each other two times during a season. Running your script produces the following 2-tuples (4,7),(4,9),(3,6),(5,10),(1,8),(2,4). Now running the script again until (7,9) pops up as a reminder reduces the number of single matches down from 12 to 9. I suppose running the script say 1000 times and look for the two sets of remainders with a maximum overlap may further reduce the number of single games. Once again, many thanks

Comment: Some additional observations: n=5 can be solved with 3 PSTS, n in {6,8,12} seems unsolvable since there are no repeated values among the 2-tuples. I will examine n in (10,11) next